# Returned array index uses record id instead of row count

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have the same script running on the same version of Opencart.

Normally this line returns an array of all products:

```
$data = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
```

and is indexed from zero to n

Here is the [product.php](http://code.google.com/p/opencart/source/browse/trunk/upload/admin/model/catalog/product.php) containing getProucts() function.

In this case (different server) it returns an array with a single value - only the last record.
Strangely, there are total of 131 records in the table, the id of last record is 191, the returned array is:

```
Array
(
[191] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 191
        [model] => Product 15
        [sku] => 
        [upc] => 
        ...
    )
)
```

Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the project uses CodeIgniter framework and it's caching library (see the line 418 for example).

There is a probability that results are taken from the cache instead of a database directly, disable cache from the configuration temporary. If the results satisfy you then you should clean a cache depending on what driver cache uses.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I was going crazy about this!
I added $this->cache->delete(product); before querying and it works as expected. Really appreciate your help!